# Samsung Smart TV request over SSL (HTTPS). Can't get an answer from server

Tags: javascript, ssl, https, samsung-smart-tv, smart-tv

Sometimes I make Smart TV applications. I've already done 2 of them. One uses HTTPS address another just HTTP. Both of them work correctly on TV, but...

I faced a problem of making request to HTTPS address. The technical supports says that some TVs may not recognize some SSL-certificates.

I've recently started to choose some of SSL-certificates and installed on my apache-server. The problem is — in one domain address request works fine, on another it does not.

Does anyone know what kind of problem it can be?

My request code is:

```
    var url = 'https://smarttv.ibecsystems.kz';

$.ajax({
    'url' : url,
    'dataType' : 'html',
    'async' : false,
    'crossDomain' : true,
    'contentType' : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',      
    'success' : function(json) {
        $('#divcontent1').html('Ok!');
    },
    'error' : function() {   
        $('#divcontent1').html('error');    
    }
});
```

https://smarttv.ibecsystems.kz - works fine, and https://api.krisha.kz - does not. Although they have the same SSL-certificate.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps that certificate is only valid for one of the two host names. What's in the CN of the certificate? What's in its Subject Alternative Names?

Comment: what is your certificate domain issued for? I've using self-signed certificate and there is no problem

Comment: @Bruno CNs of both certificates are identic to their domain names: smarttv.ibecsystems.kz and api.krisha.kz. I don't really understand what is "Subject Alternative Name". where can I see it?

Comment: @imkrisna I made a trial certificate in Comodo.com to test some of the certificates for my Smart Tv Application.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to visit your pages with chrome browser and found that api.krisha.kz certificate is invalid. Look at the message below when i'm visiting the site

> This is probably not the site you are looking for!
>   **You attempted to reach api.krisha.kz, but instead you actually reached a server identifying itself as api.kolesa.kz.** This may be
>   caused by a misconfiguration on the server or by something more
>   serious. An attacker on your network could be trying to get you to
>   visit a fake (and potentially harmful) version of api.krisha.kz.

When the other site there is no certificate problem. I think this is the problem please fix the certificate with just create self-signed certificate for the api.krisha.kz domain

Comment: Could you please check it again, because I don't see that kind of message. Can it depend on location? For instance: certificate works fine in Toronto, and not valid in my area?